# jmeter.log file overrides each time when jmeter launched in GUI as well as NON GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

JMeter Version : 3.2

My goal is to keep detailed jmeter.log file.When ever I want i can clean the log manually.

Right now when ever i launch the jmeter in GUI as well as NON GUI mode jmeter.log is overriding.

Please advise me on the configurations of

1) where do need set not to override jmeter.log?

2)I would like get detailed log i.e in debug mode.My goal is to see why sampler failed in detail.

The reason for this ask is,I ran into this situation :  I ran  1hr 30 min's test from NON GUI mode and test thrown some errors.Before  opening the jmeter.log i have launched the Jmeter GUI to view the Aggregate Report,then i realized jmeter.log overriddenjm, and also noticed jmeter.log gives just high level  details.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call jmeter with additional option `-j logfile.log` and this way it won't override jmeter.log.

Also you can change `log4j2.xml` for other login options.

You can add `-LDEBUG` for debug to [override](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) logging settings

Comment: Hi,I have tried this command jmeter -n -t E:\JMETER\PROJECT_NGP\Scripts\SL_Rel\NewProjectSetup_SL.jmx -l E:\JMETER\PROJECT_NGP\Results\SL_Rel\Build_165-20749\logs\jmeter_'yyyyMMddHHmmss'.log .It's creating but not with timestamp as jmeter_'yyyyMMddHHmmss'.log. Could please tell me where am i doing wrong and how do i get jmeter.log with datestamp-Raj

Comment: Never mind I  have fixed the timestamp of jmeter.log

Comment: Hi, Though I have uncommitted  below in the log4j2.xml in jmeter.log generated from Non GUI is still displaying high level details . 
     <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />                        
  <!-- # Enable full wire + context logging --> <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" /><!-- # Enable context logging for connection management / request execution -->
    <Logger name="org.apache.http.impl.conn" level="debug" />
    <Logger name="org.apache.http.impl.client" level="debug" />
    <Logger name="org.apache.http.client" level="debug" />

Comment: Could you please tell me where do i need to add -LDEBUG to get detailed log                                                                                      
 jmeter -n -t E:\JMETER\PROJECT_NGP\Scripts\SL_Rel\NewProjectSetup_SL.jmx -l E:\JMETER\PROJECT_NGP\Results\SL_Rel\ScriptsValidation\Build_165-20749\logs\jmeter_${__time(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,)}.log -Raj

Comment: jmeter -LDEBUG. see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override